# how to pass customized zsh function argument to in-block zmv commands?

Tags: macos, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I am creating a zsh script that batch resize, convert and rename set of images for web dev.

The zsh function is structured like below:

```bash
function img() {
    # lines of "magick -resize" and "magick mogrify -format"

    autoload zmv
    zmv '(*).(*)' '$1.$2'
}
```

How can i pass an argument from the command like `img "something"` so the zmv in-function  command can be:

```bash
zmv '(*).(*)' 'something$1.$2'
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will prefix the second argument to `zmv` with the first argument passed to `img`:

```
img() {
  zmv '(*).(*)' $1'$1.$2'
}
```

This works because the first `$1` is unquoted and thus evaluated *before* it is passed to `zmv`, whereas `'$1.$2'` is in single quotes and thus passed as a literal string.